# UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceive response not getting called

Tags: ios, swift

I am seeing a weird issue where on click of notification(Foreground and Background state),

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

is not getting called.But what makes this even more weird is that the other UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate function is getting called when notification is received:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
```

I am getting this following warning in the console

> Warning: UNUserNotificationCenter delegate received call to
> -userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:
> but the completion handler was never called.

I do have delegate set properly.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authOptions, completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
                    if granted {
                        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
                        center.delegate = self
                    }
                })
```

Here is the implementation of didReceive method.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier {
            print ("Message Closed")
            }
        else if response.actionIdentifier == UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier {
            print ("App is Open")
        }
        
        completionHandler()
    }
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: Show your implementation. I assume you do not call the completion handler.

Comment: @shallowThought I have edited my question with the implementation code.

Comment: @Kundan Got any solution to this ?

Comment: @PankajTeckchandani Yes, Clevertap was blocking it.